# Conditional value retrieve in php xpath

Tags: php, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to retrieve certain values using php xpath evaluate or query. But not able to do it successfully. 
Here is the html structure of the page:

```
<div id="productinfo">
<h2>
<span id="productname">Computer</span>
</h2>
<span id="servieidLabel" style=""> Service ID: </span>
<span id="snLabel" style="display: none"> Serial Number: </span>
<span id="servidno">12345ABCD</span>
```

I want to display only contents with style="display:none" or if style attribute is not there at all. So that the result is:- Service ID: 12345ABCD.

I have tried:

```
$ServLab = $xpath->query("//span[@id='servieidLabel']");
foreach ($ServLab as $entry) {
echo "Service Label:" ,$entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Output= Service ID:

and

```
$servid = $xpath->query("//span[@id='servidno']");
foreach ($servid as $entry) {
echo "Service Id No:" ,$entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Output = blank. Whereas the output is supposed to 12345ABCD. What am I missing?

If I try:

```
$prodid = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='productinfo']");
foreach ($prodid as $entry) {
echo $entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Output = Service ID: Serial Number:

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you stated first could be solved in a single query. Like this one:

```
$ServLab = $xpath->query("//div/span[string-length(@style) < 1]");
foreach ($ServLab as $entry) {
    echo $entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

This will provide

```
Service ID: 
12345ABCD
```

Comment: Note the added '/div' in the query. You could make this more specific by also wrapping all detail spans in a wrapper. Than select on that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this and it works. But not with the page I am working with. Just realized that these value are being inserted into the page through a javascript. So, I'll have to find out a way to get it through js rather than html.

Comment: In JS you can reuse the given xpath! Good luck with your page/site!

Comment: Tried a lot with many different methods such as XMLReader, Simple Xml and all, but have no idea how to go about it. Better I'll ask a separate question with more details about it.